# Is it possible to obtain the generic type of an interface?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Given the interface:

```
interface GenericInterface<T> {
  Class<T> getGenericType();
}
```

and the following implementation "skeletons":

```
class GenericInterfaceImpl<T> implements GenericInterface<T> { /* impl */ }

class TypedInterfaceImpl implements GenericInterface<String> { /* impl */ }
```

define an implementation for `getGenericType` in a manner that it would pass the following assertions:

```
assertEquals(new GenericInterfaceImpl<String>().getGenericType(), String.class, "Type should resolve to String.class");

assertEquals(new TypedInterfaceImpl().getGenericType(), String.class, "Type should resolve to String.class");
```

I'm perfectly aware of a good implementation that solves this problem on the `TypedInterfaceImpl` "scenario". The following code passes the assertion for the second case:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Class<T> getGenericType() {
    Type t = this.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0];
    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;

    return (Class<T>) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

But I can't find a way to get the same result if I'm working with the `GenericInterfaceImpl` version of this problem. When using the above implementation with `GenericInterfaceImpl`, the "type argument" resolves to a `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl` instead of `java.lang.String` like it does when handling `TypedInterfaceImpl`.

The Javadocs for `getGenericInterfaces` explicitly states that it will not resolve type parameters if it's not defined in the source code (for reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericInterfaces-- I'm using Java 11 in my particular case but it's the same nonetheless), so by definition, I understand that this particular method can't solve this problem.

Is there a way to solve this problem at all or is this a "core limitation" of the Java language?

Answer (score 1):

> `assertEquals(new GenericInterfaceImpl<String>().getGenericType(), String.class, "Type should resolve to String.class");`

impossible.

> `assertEquals(new TypedInterfaceImpl().getGenericType(), String.class, "Type should resolve to String.class");`

Possible, but a bad idea; it would require you to document your interface with 'when implementing this interface, you **must** pick a concrete, non-type-parameterized type for `T` or nothing works right.', which is a weird caveat.

> `Class<T> getGenericType() {`

Bad idea; the thing in the `<>` does not have to be a `Class` - for example, it could be `List<String>`, which is not representable as a class object (only `List` is, there is one object that represents all lists, there's no way to have an instance of j.l.Class that represents `List<String>`).

> The Javadocs for getGenericInterfaces

`getGenericInterfaces` is a reflective tool, but it reflects on the definition of the type only. Given `class Foo<T> implements Thingie<T>`, `getGenericInterfaces` can only be executed on the entire `Foo` class, and you get back an object that presents `Thingie<T>`. Given an instance such as `new Foo<String>()` it is **not possible** to derive String.

> Is there a way to solve this problem at all or is this a "core limitation" of the Java language?

It's a core limitation, so, no. Not directly.

One trick is to add a method:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
   public Class<T> getType();
}
```

and let implementers worry about the problem. This is still a bad idea, for example, a `Class` object cannot represent `List<String>`, so you've effectively made it impossible for Foo to properly represent anything where you want the `T` to be anything that has type params.

Take a step back instead. What are you *actually* trying to do? Nobody wakes up and goes: I know! I'll build an interface that can report its own type parameter but reified! What did you want to build? A chat app? A plugin system for photoshop?

`java.lang.Class`, with the intent to invoke `.newInstance()` on it, is a piss poor factory. Thus, if that is what you intend to do, use factories instead.

Anotehr solution, but you probably don't want this, and before you got all excited, it's got plenty of limitations, are a concept called Super Type Tokens; you can search the web if you must know.

Comment: I "generified" the problem as much as I could, but what I'm actually doing is using this feature from spring data: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior but to add generic behaviour, multi-tenancy logic to be more precise. I don't need an instance of the Type I'm obtaining but I need the type to deal with MongoOperations.

Comment: I've checked https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.customize-base-repository and in this strategy I don't have this problem because I have the EntityInformation instance in the repository to use (when overriding/extending it and etcetera) but in this way, I don't give the same flexibility for my users to only apply multi-tenancy logic to a specific repository they want, it would apply to anything that they don't override/implement themselves.